# Special loop for vuejs

Tags: html, laravel, loops, vue.js

I have this code in blade:

```
<tbody>
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= n; $i++)
        <tr data-nr="{{ $i }}" data-group="1">
            <td rowspan="2">{{ $i }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-nr="{{ $i }}" data-group="2">
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    @endfor

</tbody>
```

In html ouput is:

```
<tr data-number="1" data-group="1"></tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><td>
<tr data-number="1" data-group="2"></tr>
    <td></td>
<tr data-number="2" data-group="1"></tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><td>
<tr data-number="2" data-group="2"></tr>
    <td></td>
etc
```

How can get this html result used vuejs. Probably i can use native js for?

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="lesson, index in lessonsMax"></tr>
</tbody>
```

This format just re-enter tr, but i need two tr elements in 1 loop iteration

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! :) Could you format a bit better your question ?

Comment: Sorry. How can i get this html result used vuejs?

Comment: No, I mean the actual question, provide better indentation, maybe some visuals on what you're trying to achieve exactly. [ask]

Comment: Why do you want that output? It's not even valid.

Comment: I need a table with lessons. One tr = one lesson. The lesson have a two groups, first tr for 1 lesson, 1 group. Second tr for 1 lesson, 2 group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is doable using v-for like below:

```
<tbody v-for="i in n"> // i is index and n should be passed from vue data
        <tr data-nr="@{{ i }}" data-group="1">
            <td rowspan="2">@{{ i }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-nr="@{{ i }}" data-group="2">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

***Note:*** You might think that multiple `<tbody>` is invalid. But actually, it is **valid**! According to mozilla docs of `<table>` "You can create multiple sections within a table by using multiple `<tbody>` elements. Each may potentially have its own header row or rows; however, there can be only one `<thead>` per table!". See mozilla docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#multiple_bodies

Comment: If you want the index, you need to do `v-for="(element, index) in n"`, otherwise it will just take the element and name it `i` (in your example).

Comment: the indexes and values will be same for his case, if he passes an natural number `n` starting with 1, right?

Comment: Even if it is, I won't say that this is a good practice to use a variable just because it fits.

Comment: This code result visual is good. But tbody just duplicate n times. It not valid isn't?

Comment: @Alex Actually, it is valid! According to mozilla docs of <table> "You can create multiple sections within a table by using multiple <tbody> elements. Each may potentially have its own header row or rows; however, there can be only one <thead> per table!". See here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#multiple_bodies